# Insert values in MySQL with PHP using combobox

Tags: php, mysql, database, combobox

So, I want to insert values into MySQL, but with a combobox. I've already tried some code, but it isn't working. To insert the normal data I have the following code:

```
<input name="password" type="text" placeholder="Password"
    value="<?php echo !empty($password) ? $password : ''; ?>">
```

I'd like to create a "`user_type`" field (like `adm`, `developer`, `normal_user`), but as a `ComboBox`.

DB name: `bsh`
Table name: `customers`

I have not clue how to make it, how can I do it please?

Comment: Show us what you've tried and where it goes wrong.

Comment: I've tried to add a simple combo box with <select> and <option> and add the php code for each one but it didn't work

Comment: So show us what you tried, potential error messages, expected output and the output you're getting. We can help you to sort out problems with your _existing_ code, but we won't write it all for you. SO isn't a coding service.

Comment: I've tried the normal <select> but i was missing the php code omg.. I really want to kick my head against the wall sometimes xD
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select name="user_type">
<option value="admin" <?php echo !empty($user_type) && $user_type == 'admin' ? 'selected' : ''; ?> >Admin</option>
<option value="developer" <?php echo !empty($user_type) && $user_type == 'developer' ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>
    Developer
</option>
<option value="normal_user" <?php echo !empty($user_type) && $user_type == 'normal_user' ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>
    Normal User
</option>
</select>
```

When you submit form you will get user_type value with nam $_POST['user_type']. May be it could be helpfull to you

Comment: It kinda worked, but now my submit button disappear x.x

Comment: Nvm, it worked!! It was just need to close the select haha!
Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Thanks a lot one more time!